# Ordering dt by year and date when some months are missing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple query which groups and orders date data:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Events,
       datepart(YYYY, call_date) AS YearPart,
       datepart(MM, call_date) As MonthPart,
       datename(YYYY, call_date) AS YearName,
       dateName(MM, call_date) As MonthName
FROM rm_report
GROUP BY 
    datename(year, call_date), 
    datename(month, call_date),
    datepart(year, call_date), 
    datepart(month, call_date)
ORDER BY 
    YearPart, 
    MonthPart;
```

The issue is that the first two months of the first year contain no data.  As a result the ordering commences at the third month and then cycles to the first

```
EVENTS | YEARPART | YEARNAME | MONTHPART | MONTHNAME
3        2012       2012        3           March
6        2012       2012        4           April
6        2012       2012        5           May
6        2012       2012        6           June
6        2012       2012        7           July
6        2012       2012        8           August
6        2012       2012        9           September
6        2012       2012        10          October
6        2012       2012        11          November
6        2012       2012        12          December
6        2012       2013        1           January
6        2012       2013        2           February
```

How can I ensure that if there are no events, a 0 is allocated so that the list can be correctly ordered - that is the first entry in the `MonthPart` column is "1" and the First entry in the `YearPart` column is 2012?

We are using MS SQL.

Comment: Search for calendar table

Comment: insert some dummy rows and check.

Comment: I thought about that, however I don't have write access to the database.  It occurred to me that there may be some sort of self join that would create rows with empty (or zero) Event counts, but I can't quite work it out

Comment: I can see a calendar table may be useful, but I am not able to create one

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate all combinations of `month`s and `year`s first. And then do a `LEFT JOIN` on `rm_report`:

```
WITH CteTally(N) AS(
    SELECT N FROM(VALUES
        (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)
    )t(N)
),
CteDates(YearPart, MonthPart, YearName, MonthName) AS(
    SELECT
        DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, t.N - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, a.Y - 1900, 0))),
        DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, t.N - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, a.Y - 1900, 0))),
        DATENAME(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, t.N - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, a.Y - 1900, 0))),
        DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, t.N - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, a.Y - 1900, 0)))
    FROM(
        SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(YEAR, call_date) AS Y
        FROM rm_report
    )a
    CROSS JOIN CteTally t
)
SELECT
    COUNT(r.call_date) AS Events,
    d.YearPart,
    d.MonthPart,
    d.YearName,
    d.MonthName
FROM CteDates d
LEFT JOIN rm_report r
    ON d.YearPart = DATEPART(YEAR, r.call_date)
    AND d.YearName= DATENAME(YEAR, r.call_date)
    AND d.MonthPart = DATEPART(MONTH, r.call_date)
    AND d.MonthName = DATENAME(MONTH, r.call_date)
GROUP BY
    d.YearPart, d.YearName, d.MonthPart, d.MonthName
ORDER BY
    d.YearName, d.MonthPart
```

Comment: Ok - this is really helpful - I will try and let you know

Comment: Okay, made an update on `COUNT`. If you could just provide a sample data, I could test it for you.

Comment: mmm - I am getting an cteDates.MonthPart is invalid because it is not contained in a aggregrate function or GroupBY clause?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Just replace the second `d.YearName` in the `GROUP BY` clause with `d.MonthPart`.

Comment: I will try to create some test data and load in up asap

Comment: I works!  That is really helpful.  It never cease to amaze me how generous the Stack Overflow community is

Comment: Cool! Glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 2):

Create a temp table/CTE with one column MONTHPART which contains numbers from 1-12. Right Join your result with this table and replace NULLS with zero.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp 
  ( 
     [monthpart] INT 
  ) 

INSERT INTO #Temp (MONTHPART) Values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)

--SELECT * FROM #Temp 
SELECT [monthpart], 
       ISNULL([deptid], 0)      AS Department, 
       ISNULL(SUM([salart]), 0) AS Salary 
FROM   [DeeTest].[dbo].[employeesalary] 
       RIGHT JOIN #temp 
               ON empid = monthpart 
GROUP  BY deptid, 
          monthpart 

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: Not exactly sure how - but let me try and get back to you.

Comment: Edited, added an example.. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Calendar table as suggested by [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189369/better-way-to-generate-months-year-table) and write the query as:

```
--create Calendar table based on the max and min dates in table
DECLARE @Mincall_date DATETIME,@FromDate DATETIME, @ToDate DATETIME;
SET @Mincall_date =   ( SELECT MIN (Call_date) FROM @rm_report);
SET @FromDate= DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,@Mincall_date), 0)
SET @ToDate =  ( SELECT MAX (Call_date) FROM @rm_report);


-- just the months in that period
DECLARE @Calendar TABLE( TheDate DATETIME,TheMonth INT, TheYear INT)

INSERT INTO @Calendar       
SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @FromDate, @ToDate)+1)  
  TheDate  = DATEADD(MONTH, number, @FromDate), 
  TheMonth = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, number, @FromDate)),
  TheYear  = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, number, @FromDate))   
  FROM [master].dbo.spt_values   
  WHERE [type] = N'P' ORDER BY number;


--SELECT * FROM @Calendar

SELECT ISNULL(T.[Events],0) AS [Events],
       ISNULL(T.YearPart,C.TheYear) AS YearPart,
       ISNULL(T.MonthPart,C.TheMonth) AS MonthPart,
       ISNULL(T.YearName,DATENAME(YYYY,C.TheDate)) AS YearName,
       ISNULL(T.MonthName,DATENAME(MM,C.TheDate)) AS MonthName
FROM @Calendar C
LEFT JOIN 
(     
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Events,
       datepart(YYYY, call_date) AS YearPart,
       datepart(MM, call_date) As MonthPart,
       datename(YYYY, call_date) AS YearName,
       dateName(MM, call_date) As MonthName
FROM @rm_report 
GROUP BY 
    datename(year, call_date), 
    datename(month, call_date),
    datepart(year, call_date), 
    datepart(month, call_date)
    ) T 
     ON C.TheMonth=T.MonthPart AND C.TheYear = T.YearPart
ORDER BY 
    YearPart, 
    MonthPart;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in a simple select

```
DECLARE @rm_report table
(
    call_date datetime
)

INSERT @rm_report VALUES (GETDATE())

SELECT 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM @rm_report 
        WHERE YEAR(call_date) = year.Value AND MONTH(call_date) = month.Value
    ) AS Events,
    year.Value AS YearPart,
    month.Value AS MonthPart,
    year.Value AS YearName,
    DATENAME(MM, DATEADD(MONTH, month.Value, '2000-12-01')) AS MonthName
FROM 
    (VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)) month(Value)
    CROSS JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(call_date) Value FROM @rm_report
    ) year
```