# find the missing entries for the working days and fill the row with the values from the closest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

The problem splits into two parts.
How to check which working days are missing from my database, if some are missing then add them and fill the row with the values from the closest date.

First part, check and find the days. Should i use a gap approach like in the example below?

```
SELECT t1.col1 AS startOfGap, MIN(t2.col1) AS endOfGap  
   FROM  
   (SELECT col1 = theDate + 1  FROM sampleDates tbl1  
      WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sampleDates tbl2  
                      WHERE tbl2.theDate = tbl1.theDate + 1) 
      AND theDate <> (SELECT MAX(theDate) FROM sampleDates)) t1 
   INNER JOIN  
   (SELECT col1 = theDate - 1  FROM sampleDates tbl1  
      WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sampleDates tbl2  
                      WHERE tbl1.theDate = tbl2.theDate + 1) 
      AND theDate <> (SELECT MIN(theDate) FROM sampleDates)) t2  
   ON t1.col1 <= t2.col1 
   GROUP BY t1.col1;
```

Then i need to see which is the closest date to the one i was missing and fill the new inserted date (the one which was missing) with the values from the closest. Some time ago, I came up with something to get the closest value from a row, but this time i need to adapt it to check both down and upwards.

```
SELECT
t,A, C,Y,
COALESCE(Y, 
            (SELECT TOP (1) Y  
            FROM tableT  AS p2 
            WHERE
                  p2.Y IS NOT NULL 
                  AND p2.[t] <= p.[t] and p.C = p2.C
 ORDER BY p2.[t] DESC)) as 'YNew'
FROM tableT AS p
order by c, t
```

How to combine those into one?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Expected result

```
  Date          1mA 
20.12.2012    0.152
21.12.2012    0.181 
22 weekend so it's skipped (they are skipped automatically)  
23 weekend -,- 
24 missing  
25 missing 
26 missing
27.12.2012    0.173
28.12.2012    0.342


  Date          1mA 
20.12.2012    0.152
21.12.2012    0.181 
22 weekend so it's skipped (they are skipped automatically)  
23 weekend    0.181
24 missing    0.181
25 missing    0.181
26 missing    0.173
27.12.2012    0.173
28.12.2012    0.342
```

So, 24,25,26 are not even there with null values. They are simply not there.

**EDIT 2:** 
For taking the closest value, let's consider the scenario in which i'm always looking above. So always going back 1 when it's missing.

```
Date          1mA 
    20.12.2012    0.152
    21.12.2012    0.181 
    22 weekend so it's skipped (they are skipped automatically)  
    23 weekend    0.181
    24 missing    0.181
    25 missing    0.181
    26 missing    0.181 
    27.12.2012    0.173
    28.12.2012    0.342
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: So what should the expected results be?  22 and 23 pick up the value from 21 *(0.181)*?  and 24 and 25 pick up the value from 26 *(0.173)*?  But what about 24?

Comment: those which are at equal distance should take either the value from above or below. the rest you got it right @MatBailie

Comment: If it's easier for you, I would also greatly apreciate a solution in which i'm always looking at the value above. What i really need now, is a way to insert those missing dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these types of query you gain significant performance benefits from creating a calendar table containing every date you'll ever need to test.  *(If you're familiar with the term "dimension tables", this is just one such table to enumerate every date of interest.)*

Also, the query as a whole can become significantly simpler.

```
SELECT
   cal.calendar_date   AS data_date,
   CASE WHEN prev_data.gap <= next_data.gap
        THEN prev_data.data_value
        ELSE COALESCE(next_data.data_value, prev_data.data_value)
   END
       AS data_value
FROM
    calendar   AS cal
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP(1)
        data_date,
        data_value,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, data_date, cal.calendar_date)   AS gap
    FROM
        data_table
    WHERE
        data_date <= cal.calendar_date
    ORDER BY
        data_date DESC
)
   prev_data
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP(1)
        data_date,
        data_value,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, cal.calendar_date, data_date)   AS gap
    FROM
        data_table
    WHERE
        data_date >  cal.calendar_date
    ORDER BY
        data_date ASC
)
   next_data
WHERE
   cal.calendar_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'
;
```

***EDIT*** Reply to your comment with a different requirement

To always get "the value above" is easier, and to insert those values in to a table is easy enough...

```
INSERT INTO
    data_table
SELECT
   cal.calendar_date,
   prev_data.data_value
FROM
    calendar   AS cal
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP(1)
        data_date,
        data_value
    FROM
        data_table
    WHERE
        data_date <= cal.calendar_date
    ORDER BY
        data_date DESC
)
   prev_data
WHERE
       cal.calendar_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'
   AND cal.calendar_date <> prev_data.data_date
;
```

***Note:*** You could add `WHERE prev_data.gap > 0` to the bigger query above to only get dates that don't already have data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can i use more than 1 year for cal.calendar_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31' ? I want from 01.04.2009 and asOfDate ...or getdate()

Comment: @viorelmunteanu - you need to create that table, and then you put all the dates that you'll ever need in it *(Generally I fill it with every date from 2000-01-01 to 2070-12-31)*, then you choose what *(if any)* range you want to put in the where clause.

Comment: In my database all the weekends are skipped. How can i make sure that this won't add any date which is in the weekend

Comment: @viorelmunteanu - Add a field to your calendar table that is `is_weekend` and then include `WHERE is_weekend = 0` in your query.  Or, even more specifically, add an `data_date_skipped` in-case you skip additional dates too *(bank-holidays, religious-holidays, known system failures, etc)*.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189369/better-way-to-generate-months-year-table) you can write a query as:

```
-- create a calendar table at run time if you don't have one:

DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME, @ToDate DATETIME;
SET @FromDate = (select min(Date) from test);
SET @ToDate = (select max(Date) from test);


--Get final result:
select Tblfinal.Date,
       case when Tblfinal.[1mA] is null then 
           ( select top 1 T2.[1mA] from Test T2 
             where T2.Date < Tblfinal.Date and T2.[1mA] > 0
             order by T2.Date desc)
       else Tblfinal.[1mA] end as [1mA]
from       

(
    select isnull( C.TheDate, T.Date) as Date ,T.[1mA]      
    from Test T
    right join  (
        -- all days in that period
        SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @FromDate, @ToDate)+1) 
          TheDate = DATEADD(DAY, number, @FromDate)
          FROM [master].dbo.spt_values 
          WHERE [type] = N'P'
                )C on T.Date= C.TheDate
) Tblfinal
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/KLUA16369)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Use a Tally Table to generate all dates from `@startDate` to `@endDate`. Then with that, use a `LEFT JOIN` and `OUTER APPLY` to achieve the desired result:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da650/2/0)

```
;WITH E1(N) AS(
    SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(N)
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b),
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b),
CteTally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate) + 1)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))
    FROM E4
),
CteDates(dt) AS(
    SELECT
        DATEADD(DAY, N-1, @startDate)
    FROM CteTally ct
)
SELECT
    d.dt,
    [1mA] = ISNULL(t.[1mA], x.[1mA])
FROM CteDates d
LEFT JOIN tbl t
    ON t.Date = d.dt
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 [1mA]
    FROM tbl
    WHERE [Date] < d.dt
    ORDER BY [Date] DESC
)x
WHERE
    ((DATEPART(dw, d.dt) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)
```

The `WHERE` clause

```
((DATEPART(dw, d.dt) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)
```

excludes weekends regardless of `@@DATEFIRST`.

**RESULT**

```
|         dt |   1mA |
|------------|-------|
| 2012-12-20 | 0.152 |
| 2012-12-21 | 0.181 |
| 2012-12-24 | 0.181 |
| 2012-12-25 | 0.181 |
| 2012-12-26 | 0.181 |
| 2012-12-27 | 0.173 |
| 2012-12-28 | 0.342 |
```

Answer (score 1):

using recursive CTE we can generate date sequence:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/27913/4)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table sample (date datetime, data money)
insert sample (date, data)
values 
  ('2015-01-02', 0.2),
  ('2015-01-03', 0.3),
  ('2015-01-07', 0.4),
  ('2015-01-08', 0.5),
  ('2015-01-09', 0.6),
  ('2015-01-21', 0.7),
  ('2015-01-22', 0.8),
  ('2015-01-27', 0.9),
  ('2015-01-28', 0.11),
  ('2015-01-30', 0.12)
```

**Query 1**:

```
declare @d1 datetime = '2015-01-01', @d2 datetime = '2015-01-31'

;with dates as (
  select @d1 as date
  union all
  select dateadd(day, 1, date)
  from dates
  where dateadd(day, 1, date) <= @d2
), lo_hi as (
  select 
    *,
    (select top 1 date from sample s where s.date <= d.date order by s.date desc) as lower_date,
    (select top 1 date from sample s where s.date >= d.date order by s.date asc) as higher_date
  from dates d 
), lo_hi_diff as (
  select 
    *, 
    isnull(datediff(day, lower_date, date), 100000) as lo_diff,
    isnull(datediff(day, date, higher_date), 100000) as hi_diff
  from lo_hi
)
  select 
    *,
    case 
      when lo_diff <= hi_diff then
        (select top 1 data from sample where date = lower_date)
      else
        (select top 1 data from sample where date = higher_date)
    end as new_data
  from lo_hi_diff d
    left join sample s on d.date = s.date
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/27913/4/0)**:

```
|                      date |                lower_date |               higher_date | lo_diff | hi_diff |                      date |   data | new_data |
|---------------------------|---------------------------|---------------------------|---------|---------|---------------------------|--------|----------|
| January, 01 2015 00:00:00 |                    (null) | January, 02 2015 00:00:00 |  100000 |       1 |                    (null) | (null) |      0.2 |
| January, 02 2015 00:00:00 | January, 02 2015 00:00:00 | January, 02 2015 00:00:00 |       0 |       0 | January, 02 2015 00:00:00 |    0.2 |      0.2 |
| January, 03 2015 00:00:00 | January, 03 2015 00:00:00 | January, 03 2015 00:00:00 |       0 |       0 | January, 03 2015 00:00:00 |    0.3 |      0.3 |
| January, 04 2015 00:00:00 | January, 03 2015 00:00:00 | January, 07 2015 00:00:00 |       1 |       3 |                    (null) | (null) |      0.3 |
| January, 05 2015 00:00:00 | January, 03 2015 00:00:00 | January, 07 2015 00:00:00 |       2 |       2 |                    (null) | (null) |      0.3 |
| January, 06 2015 00:00:00 | January, 03 2015 00:00:00 | January, 07 2015 00:00:00 |       3 |       1 |                    (null) | (null) |      0.4 |
| January, 07 2015 00:00:00 | January, 07 2015 00:00:00 | January, 07 2015 00:00:00 |       0 |       0 | January, 07 2015 00:00:00 |    0.4 |      0.4 |
| January, 08 2015 00:00:00 | January, 08 2015 00:00:00 | January, 08 2015 00:00:00 |       0 |       0 | January, 08 2015 00:00:00 |    0.5 |      0.5 |
| January, 09 2015 00:00:00 | January, 09 2015 00:00:00 | January, 09 2015 00:00:00 |       0 |       0 | January, 09 2015 00:00:00 |    0.6 |      0.6 |
| January, 10 2015 00:00:00 | January, 09 2015 00:00:00 | January, 21 2015 00:00:00 |       1 |      11 |                    (null) | (null) |      0.6 |
| January, 11 2015 00:00:00 | January, 09 2015 00:00:00 | January, 21 2015 00:00:00 |       2 |      10 |                    (null) | (null) |      0.6 |
| January, 12 2015 00:00:00 | January, 09 2015 00:00:00 | January, 21 2015 00:00:00 |       3 |       9 |                    (null) | (null) |      0.6 |
| January, 13 2015 00:00:00 | January, 09 2015 00:00:00 | January, 21 2015 00:00:00 |       4 |       8 |                    (null) | (null) |      0.6 |
| January, 14 2015 00:00:00 | January, 09 2015 00:00:00 | January, 21 2015 00:00:00 |       5 |       7 |                    (null) | (null) |      0.6 |
| January, 15 2015 00:00:00 | January, 09 2015 00:00:00 | January, 21 2015 00:00:00 |       6 |       6 |                    (null) | (null) |      0.6 |
| January, 16 2015 00:00:00 | January, 09 2015 00:00:00 | January, 21 2015 00:00:00 |       7 |       5 |                    (null) | (null) |      0.7 |
| January, 17 2015 00:00:00 | January, 09 2015 00:00:00 | January, 21 2015 00:00:00 |       8 |       4 |                    (null) | (null) |      0.7 |
| January, 18 2015 00:00:00 | January, 09 2015 00:00:00 | January, 21 2015 00:00:00 |       9 |       3 |                    (null) | (null) |      0.7 |
| January, 19 2015 00:00:00 | January, 09 2015 00:00:00 | January, 21 2015 00:00:00 |      10 |       2 |                    (null) | (null) |      0.7 |
| January, 20 2015 00:00:00 | January, 09 2015 00:00:00 | January, 21 2015 00:00:00 |      11 |       1 |                    (null) | (null) |      0.7 |
| January, 21 2015 00:00:00 | January, 21 2015 00:00:00 | January, 21 2015 00:00:00 |       0 |       0 | January, 21 2015 00:00:00 |    0.7 |      0.7 |
| January, 22 2015 00:00:00 | January, 22 2015 00:00:00 | January, 22 2015 00:00:00 |       0 |       0 | January, 22 2015 00:00:00 |    0.8 |      0.8 |
| January, 23 2015 00:00:00 | January, 22 2015 00:00:00 | January, 27 2015 00:00:00 |       1 |       4 |                    (null) | (null) |      0.8 |
| January, 24 2015 00:00:00 | January, 22 2015 00:00:00 | January, 27 2015 00:00:00 |       2 |       3 |                    (null) | (null) |      0.8 |
| January, 25 2015 00:00:00 | January, 22 2015 00:00:00 | January, 27 2015 00:00:00 |       3 |       2 |                    (null) | (null) |      0.9 |
| January, 26 2015 00:00:00 | January, 22 2015 00:00:00 | January, 27 2015 00:00:00 |       4 |       1 |                    (null) | (null) |      0.9 |
| January, 27 2015 00:00:00 | January, 27 2015 00:00:00 | January, 27 2015 00:00:00 |       0 |       0 | January, 27 2015 00:00:00 |    0.9 |      0.9 |
| January, 28 2015 00:00:00 | January, 28 2015 00:00:00 | January, 28 2015 00:00:00 |       0 |       0 | January, 28 2015 00:00:00 |   0.11 |     0.11 |
| January, 29 2015 00:00:00 | January, 28 2015 00:00:00 | January, 30 2015 00:00:00 |       1 |       1 |                    (null) | (null) |     0.11 |
| January, 30 2015 00:00:00 | January, 30 2015 00:00:00 | January, 30 2015 00:00:00 |       0 |       0 | January, 30 2015 00:00:00 |   0.12 |     0.12 |
| January, 31 2015 00:00:00 | January, 30 2015 00:00:00 |                    (null) |       1 |  100000 |                    (null) | (null) |     0.12 |
```