# retrieve and add the missing dates excluding weekends while looping with a cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to add the missing dates in my table (excluding the weekends) for all id's. There are over 100 different id's i have to loop through.
So far i have the following code:

```
declare @date_idx datetime
declare @date_missing datetime
declare @tsID int
declare @MyCursor CURSOR
--declare @tsIDnew int
set @date_idx = '20090101'
set @MyCursor = CURSOR fast_forward
FOR
    select 
    tsID
    --,@tsIDnew
    from #tempTimeSeriesDateAdded
    open @MyCursor
    fetch next from @MyCursor
    into @tsId
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    while datediff(dd, @date_idx, '20150529') >= 0
    BEGIN
        set @date_missing = (select rateDate from #tempTimeSeriesDateAdded where rateDate = @date_idx and tsID = @tsID )
        if DATEPART(DW, @date_idx) NOT IN (1,7) and @date_missing is null
        --insert @date_idx into 
        PRINT @date_idx 
        SET @date_idx = DATEADD(dd,1,@date_idx)
    END
fetch next from @MyCursor
--into @tsIDnew 
end
close @MyCursor
Deallocate @MyCursor
```

How to get this to work?
I'm quite new to sql and started with cursors yesterday (i know a set or a join would probably work better, i'm open to solutions).

thanks

**edit:**
i have something like this:

```
Ratedate       rate 
20.12.2012    0.152
21.12.2012    0.181 
22 weekend so it's skipped (they are skipped automatically)  
23 weekend -,- 
24 missing  
25 missing 
26 missing
27.12.2012    0.173
28.12.2012    0.342
```

and i would like something like this:

```
rateDate       rate 
20.12.2012    0.152
21.12.2012    0.181 
22 weekend so it's skipped (they are skipped automatically)  
23 weekend    0.181
24 missing    0.181
25 missing    0.181
26 missing    0.181 
27.12.2012    0.173
28.12.2012    0.342
```

But i need to perform this for every tsId in the list.

EDIT 2: Not a duplicate of my previous post. Since this is taken further, wrote code and need a loop

Comment: Perhaps you could visually illustrate the current data in your table and your desired data, in order to make it clearer what you are trying to do?  A few rows showing _before_ and _after_ should do it?

Comment: This is what a Calendar table is for. Create a table with all the possible dates, add the attributes you'll need to filter on (weekday, holiday, etc), and put it on the preserving side of outer join.

Comment: I would like to avoid the calendar table and use this somehow

Comment: What should be the value for 23,24,25 and 26 in `rateDate` column? @viorel munteanu

Comment: Didn't you ask this already?http://stackoverflow.com/a/32096001/2203084

Comment: 23.12.2012 , 24.12.2012, 25.12.2012, 26.12.2012. I have check for missing dates which are not in the weekend and insert them. Then on the rate column take the value from the one before (an entery which exists). And i have to do this for different id's. Hence the cursor, this operation has to be performed for every id.

Comment: possible duplicate of [find the missing entries for the working days and fill the row with the values from the closest date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32094670/find-the-missing-entries-for-the-working-days-and-fill-the-row-with-the-values-f)

Comment: yes, but the problem changed since now i have to also think about looping through the ids. I figured out how to select the missing values. You can see it in the query above (but only when i use a value, and not a variable: ex:`rateDate = @date_idx and tsID = @tsID works with ='20'). `

Comment: + i don't want to create a calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the cursor and while loop.
This script give you all the missing dates between start and end dates along with the Ids:

```
--create table #tempTimeSeriesDateAdded (tsid int)
declare @tempTimeSeriesDateAdded table (tsID int, dt datetime)
insert into @tempTimeSeriesDateAdded values
(1, '20150810'), (1, '20150818'), (1, '20150819'), (1, '20150820'), (1, '20150825')
, (2, '20150810'), (2, '20150812'), (2, '20150817'), (2, '20150820'), (2, '20150825')

declare @date_start datetime = '20150809'
declare @date_end datetime = '20150829'

-- all date between start and end
; with list as (
    Select dt = @date_start
    Union All
    Select DATEADD(day, 1, dt) From list
    Where  DATEADD(day, 1, dt) <= @date_end 
)
--Insert Into YourTable(date, id)
Select i.dt, i.tsID From (
    Select tsID, dt
    From (select distinct tsID from @tempTimeSeriesDateAdded) as idx
    Cross Join list as l
    where DATEPART(dw, dt) between 2 and 6
) as i 
Left Join @tempTimeSeriesDateAdded as d on d.dt = i.dt and d.tsID = i.tsID
Where d.tsID is null
Order By i.tsID, i.dt
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

You only have to add the rate and insert it.

Comment: thanks, is this ok as it is: `set @date_missing = (select rateDate from #tempTimeSeriesDateAdded where rateDate = @date_idx and tsID = @tsID )
        if DATEPART(DW, @date_idx) NOT IN (1,7) and @date_missing is null
        --insert @date_idx into 
        PRINT @date_idx 
        SET @date_idx = DATEADD(dd,1,@date_idx)`  . I'm not sure where to insert it in your script @Julien

Comment: I added the insert in my script. You don't have to set @date_missing to something. I select (or insert) all missing value all together for each ID. It does not do it one by one like your coursor does. You can replace my table variable by your table, change start and end date and execute. it will show you what is missing. uncomment the insert if you want to insert.

Comment: thanks for the info, I'm bit lost in this since i don't usually use big queries. But i get the logic. If i uncomment the insert and put this `Insert Into #tempTimeSeriesDateAdded(rateDate, tsID)` i am getting `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'rateName', table 'tempdb.dbo.#tempTimeSeriesDateAdded`

Comment: I don't really know your data model. You must update the query and add whatever is missing in the insert/select

Comment: what i can't figure out now is where to specify my own tsID from a db (which ranges from 1 to 108). Because you insert some sample data with some id's.  @Julien Vavasseur

Comment: From (select distinct tsID from @tempTimeSeriesDateAdded where tsID >= 1 and tsID <= 108) as idx

Comment: ok, but still shows me the values from the insert, as in tsID 1 and 2 and only those

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87497/discussion-between-julien-vavasseur-and-viorel-munteanu).