# Count and group data by Year/month

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table that contains task data going back 12 months.

Here's an example:

[image]

I am trying to write a query that displays each month and the count of tickets that were open up until that month by their rating. Output example below:

[image: 222]

I created the following SQL statement to count by day:

```
SELECT 
    created, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN rating = ‘high’ THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS high,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN rating = ‘med’ THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS med,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN rating = ‘low’ THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS low 
FROM 
    taskDB 
GROUP BY 
    created 
ORDER BY 
    created ASC
```

I am not sure how to group by month and get the proper count up until that month? Is there a better way to do this? My end goal is to display this data as a timeline chart where the yAxis is ticket count and xAxis is the date(yea/month). There will be a line for each “rating”.

**UPDATE 8/14/2020**

I tried out a couple of the answers there and they seem to count the amount of tickets open only for each month and not from each month + all prior months. I created a SQL script with some test data so everyone can see what i'm working with:

```
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[taskDB](
    [ticket] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [created] [date] NULL,
    [closed] [date] NULL,
    [rating] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023345', CAST(N'2019-09-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-01-17' AS Date), N'Low')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023346', CAST(N'2019-08-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-03' AS Date), N'Critical')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023347', CAST(N'2019-09-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-09-20' AS Date), N'Critical')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023348', CAST(N'2019-08-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-08-06' AS Date), N'Critical')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023349', CAST(N'2020-08-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-08-05' AS Date), N'Medium')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023350', CAST(N'2019-08-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), N'Medium')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023351', CAST(N'2019-12-22' AS Date), CAST(N'' AS Date), N'High')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023352', CAST(N'2019-11-07' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-08-05' AS Date), N'Medium')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023353', CAST(N'2020-08-02' AS Date), CAST(N'' AS Date), N'Low')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023354', CAST(N'2019-08-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), N'Medium')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023355', CAST(N'2019-010-02' AS Date), CAST(N'' AS Date), N'Low')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023356', CAST(N'2019-08-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), N'Critical')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023357', CAST(N'2019-08-06' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-07-05' AS Date), N'Critical')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023358', CAST(N'2019-10-04' AS Date), CAST(N'' AS Date), N'Low')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023359', CAST(N'2019-12-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-02-25' AS Date), N'High')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023360', CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), N'Medium')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023361', CAST(N'2020-08-02' AS Date), CAST(N'' AS Date), N'High')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023362', CAST(N'2019-09-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-06' AS Date), N'Critical')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023363', CAST(N'2019-10-03' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-11-08' AS Date), N'High')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023365', CAST(N'2019-10-03' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-12-08' AS Date), N'N/A')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023364', CAST(N'2019-11-03' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-11-05' AS Date), N'High')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023366', CAST(N'2020-06-03' AS Date), CAST(N'' AS Date), N'High')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023368', CAST(N'2019-08-03' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), N'High')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023367', CAST(N'2019-11-03' AS Date), CAST(N'' AS Date), N'N/A')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023371', CAST(N'2019-08-03' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), N'N/A')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating]) VALUES (N'023370', CAST(N'2019-08-03' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), N'Critical')
GO
```

I tried the following from @GMB which is close but does not seem to give me the correct results as there is negative numbers and the blank closed fields are coming back as 1900-01-01.

```
select 
    year(x.dt) yyyy,
    month(x.dt) mm,
    sum(sum(case when x.rating = 'low'    then cnt else 0 end)) 
        over(order by year(x.dt), month(x.dt)) low,
    sum(sum(case when x.rating = 'medium' then cnt else 0 end)) 
        over(order by year(x.dt), month(x.dt)) medium,
    sum(sum(case when x.rating = 'high'   then cnt else 0 end)) 
        over(order by year(x.dt), month(x.dt)) high
from [TestDB].[dbo].[taskDB] t
cross apply (values
    (rating, created, 1),
    (rating, closed, -1)
) as x(rating, dt, cnt)
where x.dt is not null
group by year(x.dt), month(x.dt)
order by year(x.dt), month(x.dt)
```

The results for this query:

[image]

**UPDATE 8/14/2020**

The revised query by @iceblade seems to be the most correct at this point. The only thing it does not account for is if a ticket was opened and closed in the same month, i believe it should be counted. Here is the query:

```
declare @FromDate datetime, 
        @ToDate datetime;

SET @FromDate = (Select min(created) From [dbo].[taskDB]);
SET @ToDate = (Select max(created) From [dbo].[taskDB]);

declare @openTicketsByMonth table (firstDayNextMonth datetime, year int, month int, Low int, Medium int, High int, Critical int, NA int)

Insert into @openTicketsByMonth(firstDayNextMonth, year, month)

Select top  (datediff(month, @FromDate, @ToDate) + 1) 
              dateadd(month, number + 1, @FromDate),
              year(dateadd(month, number, @FromDate)),
              month(dateadd(month, number, @FromDate))
              from [master].dbo.spt_values 
              where [type] = N'P' order by number;

update R
Set R.Low = (Select count(1) from [dbo].[taskDB] where rating = 'Low' and created < R.firstDayNextMonth and (closed >= R.firstDayNextMonth or closed = '' or closed is null)),
    R.Medium = (Select count(1) from [dbo].[taskDB] where rating = 'Medium' and created < R.firstDayNextMonth and (closed >= R.firstDayNextMonth or closed = '' or closed is null)),
    R.High = (Select count(1) from [dbo].[taskDB] where rating = 'High' and created < R.firstDayNextMonth and (closed >= R.firstDayNextMonth or closed = '' or closed is null)),
    R.Critical = (Select count(1) from [dbo].[taskDB] where rating = 'Critical' and created < R.firstDayNextMonth and (closed >= R.firstDayNextMonth or closed = '' or closed is null)),
    R.NA = (Select count(1) from [dbo].[taskDB] where rating = 'N/A' and created < R.firstDayNextMonth and (closed >= R.firstDayNextMonth or closed = '' or closed is null))
From @openTicketsByMonth R

select  year,
        month,
        Low,
        Medium,
        High,
        Critical,
        NA 
from @openTicketsByMonth
```

and the output from the query based on the data above:

[image]

If you look at 2019/8 there are 2 tickets that are critical that were opened and stayed open past that month but there are 3 critical tickets that were opened and closed in the same month. I believe those should be counted.

**UPDATE 8/17/2020**

The query @iceblade posted has been edited and is confirmed to produce the proper results. Answer has been marked accordingly.

Comment: Please elaborate on "I am trying to write a query that displays each month and the count of tickets that were open up until that month by their rating.".

Comment: So lets take last month for instance, i want to display all tickets that would have been open if i ran a query to just display ALL open tickets last month BY rating and so on going back month by month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your new input, I created a table variable with all the year/month between the first and last ticket, I used this article for that:
[better way to generate months/year table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189369/better-way-to-generate-months-year-table)
Then I update each category, counting the tickets that have a closed date > first day of each month. This should give you the desired result.

**Updated 8/17/2020 - Modified query to include tickets that were closed before the end of the month.**

```
declare @FromDate datetime, 
        @ToDate datetime;

SET @FromDate = (Select min(created) From [dbo].[taskDB]);
SET @ToDate = (Select max(created) From [dbo].[taskDB]);

declare @openTicketsByMonth table (firstDayOfMonth datetime, firstDayNextMonth datetime, year int, month int, Low int, Medium int, High int, Critical int, NA int)

Insert into @openTicketsByMonth(firstDayOfMonth, firstDayNextMonth, year, month)

Select top  (datediff(month, @FromDate, @ToDate) + 1) 
                                                  dateadd(month, number, @FromDate),
              dateadd(month, number + 1, @FromDate),
             year(dateadd(month, number, @FromDate)),
              month(dateadd(month, number, @FromDate))
              from [master].dbo.spt_values 
              where [type] = N'P' order by number;

update R
Set R.Low = (Select count(1) from [dbo].[taskDB] where rating = 'Low' and created < R.firstDayNextMonth and (closed >= R.firstDayOfMonth or closed = '' or closed is null)),
    R.Medium = (Select count(1) from [dbo].[taskDB] where rating = 'Medium' and created < R.firstDayNextMonth and (closed >= R.firstDayOfMonth or closed = '' or closed is null)),
    R.High = (Select count(1) from [dbo].[taskDB] where rating = 'High' and created < R.firstDayNextMonth and (closed >= R.firstDayOfMonth or closed = '' or closed is null)),
    R.Critical = (Select count(1) from [dbo].[taskDB] where rating = 'Critical' and created < R.firstDayNextMonth and (closed >= R.firstDayOfMonth or closed = '' or closed is null)),
    R.NA = (Select count(1) from [dbo].[taskDB] where rating = 'N/A' and created < R.firstDayNextMonth and (closed >= R.firstDayOfMonth or closed = '' or closed is null))
From @openTicketsByMonth R

select  year,
        month,
        Low,
        Medium,
        High,
        Critical,
        NA 
from @openTicketsByMonth
```

Comment: This is the closest one Yet! But base on the ticket data the only tickets that are open in Aug 2020 is 3 highs and 3 lows. When i run this it says 2 lows, 1 medium, 2 highs and 1 critical are open. looking at your counting logic it seems correct but something is throwing it off.

Comment: I think the issue was with the starting date for comparison, I updated the query adding 1 month, so the comparison will be for tickets opened before the first day of next month, and that hasn't been closed before that date. Now it's showing me for Aug 2020: 3 highs, 3 lows, 1 N/A

Comment: Great and yes this works but there is one more issue that i do not believe this query accounts for. If a ticket is opened and closed within the same month, i feel like that should be counted also.

Comment: That will depend on what you want to show, right now the query shows if there are open tickets at the end of the month. I can update the query so it shows if there where open tickets during the month, but this will increase the amounts. For ex, Aug 2020 will be: Low: 3, Medium: 2, High: 3, Critical: 1, NA: 1

Comment: Yes id like to see tickets open at the end of the month and any that were opened and then closed in that same month.

Comment: Just updated the query to show tickets that were closed before the end of the month.

Answer (score 3):

You need a calendar table/view with the date ranges for the last twelve months, e.g.

```
"year/month"  month_begin    month_end
     2019/08   2019-08-01   2019-08-31
```

and then a join checking for overlapping date ranges:

```
-- based on @iceblade's answer
declare @FromDate date, 
        @ToDate date;

SET @FromDate = (Select min(created) From [dbo].[taskDB]);
SET @ToDate = (Select max(created) From [dbo].[taskDB]);

declare @calendar table (Month_begin date, month_end date, year int, month int)

Insert into @calendar(Month_begin, month_end, year, month)

Select top  (datediff(month, @FromDate, @ToDate) + 1) 
              dateadd(month, number, @FromDate),
              dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(month, number + 1, @FromDate)),
              year(dateadd(month, number, @FromDate)),
              month(dateadd(month, number, @FromDate))
              from [master].dbo.spt_values 
              where [type] = N'P' order by number;
              
              
select c.year,c.month,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN rating = 'Low' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as low,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN rating = 'Medium' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as med,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN rating = 'High' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as high,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN rating = 'Critical' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as critical,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN rating = 'N/A' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as na
FROM taskDB as t join @calendar as c 
  -- overlapping periods
  on t.created <= c.month_end
 and (t.closed >= c.month_begin  or t.closed is null)
GROUP BY c.year,c.month
ORDER BY c.year,c.month
```

Adding a varition based on GMB's, no join to a calendar and probably more efficient for your actual data. This just modifies the closing date to next month:

```
select 
    year(x.dt) yyyy,
    month(x.dt) mm,
    sum(sum(case when x.rating = 'Low'    then cnt else 0 end)) 
        over(order by year(x.dt), month(x.dt)
             rows unbounded preceding) low,
    sum(sum(case when x.rating = 'Medium' then cnt else 0 end)) 
        over(order by year(x.dt), month(x.dt)
             rows unbounded preceding) medium,
    sum(sum(case when x.rating = 'High'   then cnt else 0 end)) 
        over(order by year(x.dt), month(x.dt)
             rows unbounded preceding) high,
    sum(sum(case when x.rating = 'Critical'   then cnt else 0 end)) 
        over(order by year(x.dt), month(x.dt)
             rows unbounded preceding) critical,
    sum(sum(case when x.rating = 'N/A'   then cnt else 0 end)) 
        over(order by year(x.dt), month(x.dt)
             rows unbounded preceding) na
from taskDB t
cross apply (values
    (rating, created, 1),
    -- closed in next month
    (rating, dateadd(m,1,closed), -1)
   ) as x(rating, dt, cnt)
where dt <= getdate() -- no rows past today
group by year(x.dt), month(x.dt)
order by year(x.dt), month(x.dt)
```

There's a minor difference, #2 will skip months with no tickets, but I doubt this exists.

This seems to be what you want, see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=14b855fb5c3505cfd0894f1c958c8d3d)

Comment: I didn't include the open rows (= NULL dates), thus the result was removing them

Answer (score 3):

One option uses a lateral join and conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    year(x.dt) yyyy,
    month(x.dt) mm,
    sum(sum(case when x.rating = 'low'    then cnt else 0 end)) 
        over(order by year(x.dt), month(x.dt)) low,
    sum(sum(case when x.rating = 'medium' then cnt else 0 end)) 
        over(order by year(x.dt), month(x.dt)) medium,
    sum(sum(case when x.rating = 'high'   then cnt else 0 end)) 
        over(order by year(x.dt), month(x.dt)) high,
from taskDB t
cross apply (values
    (rating, created, 1),
    (rating, closed, -1)
) as x(rating, dt, cnt)
where x.dt is not null
group by year(x.dt), month(x.dt)
order by year(x.dt), month(x.dt)
```

You can filter as needed on a given period by turning this to a subquery and using a `where` clause in the outer query.

Comment: I tried this but I have two problems, when the "closed" column is empty or the ticket is not closed yet, SQL sets its value at "1900-01-01" so i think that is skewing the data. Also it does not seem to be counting all tickets up until the month that have not been closed yet.

Comment: @mister.cake: I changed the query so it handles empty closure dates. This should give you the result you want.

Comment: With the addition of the "where x.dt is not null" it seems it is just not counting those dates when the closed field is "1900-01-01". Basically i think (rating, closed, -1) should only happen if the date in "closed" is NOT "1900-01-01".

Comment: @mister.cake: in the data you showed, it looks like `closed` has `null` values - but I can’t see your real data. You can change the `where` clause to what suits you best.

Comment: i added some more information based on this post above with a sample script. you can see the output i am getting,

Answer (score 1):

Group by year and month instead of the full date.

```
   select convert(varchar(max), year(created)) + '/' + right('0' + convert(varchar(max), month(created)),2) as Created
       , COUNT(CASE WHEN rating = ‘high’ THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as high,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN rating = ‘med’ THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as med,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN rating = ‘low’ THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as low FROM taskDB 
    GROUP BY convert(varchar(max), year(created)) + '/' + right('0' + convert(varchar(max), month(created)),2)
ORDER BY convert(varchar(max), year(created)) + '/' + right('0' + convert(varchar(max), month(created)),2) ASC
```

Comment: This query does not seem to count all tickets that would have been OPEN from each month going back and account for if the ticket has been closed by the month/year

Answer (score 1):

> Make use of WIth clause in which convert the date in the required
> format and then group on that formatted date.

```
With TempTaskDB As (    
SELECT convert(varchar(20), datepart(year, created)) + '/' + convert(varchar(20), datepart(month, created)) as CreatedDate,rating
from taskDB)
Select CreatedDate,
COUNT(CASE WHEN rating = ‘high’ THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS high,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN rating = ‘med’ THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS med,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN rating = ‘low’ THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS low
from TempTaskDB
group by CreatedDate
Order by CreatedDate Asc
```